# Orchard.sdf is already in use error on deployment

Tags: orchardcms, web-deployment, orchardcms-1.6

I'm deploying my Orchard website and i was successful in doing that to my desired server. But all of a sudden,i'm getting an error like this-
"Web deployment task failed. (The file 'Orchard.sdf' is in use.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_FILE_IN_USE.)"
Can any one let me know ,how to fix this?As it is occuring repeatedly even after me closing the website and turn off the iis.

Answer (score 0):

First, try to stop the application during deployment, through the hoster's control panel, or using an app_offline.html file. You can also try to simply restart it by touching web.config. As apparently you already tried that, it means that a handle to the file was not freed. Most likely, it's the database engine itself. If you have access, try to restart that. Otherwise, ask your hoster. If that still fails, somebody will have to diagnose it with a tool like Process Explorer that allows one to search for handles.

In the end, using SqlCe in production is not reasonable. You should switch to a full database engine.